# Enzyme - Invariant Violation: Could not find "store"

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I am trying to test the DISCONNECTED version of a component. For some reason, Enzyme is complaining about the store. I don't know why. I imported the disconnected version.

Here is my test:

```
import { Board } from '../components/Board/Board'; 
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'; 
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; 

describe('Board', () => {
    it('contains .board when currentBoardId is truthy', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Router><Board currentBoardId={true} /></Router>); 
        expect(wrapper.contains(<Redirect to="/navigation" />)).toEqual(false); 
    }); 
});
```

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import BoardForm from '../BoardForm/BoardForm';
import BoardToDos from '../BoardToDos/BoardToDos';   
import BoardCompleted from '../BoardCompleted/BoardCompleted'; 
import './Board.css';  

export class Board extends React.Component {
    render() {

        if(!this.props.currentBoardId) {
            return (
                <Redirect to="/navigation" />
            )
        }
        return (
            <div className="board">
                <BoardForm />
                <BoardToDos />
                <BoardCompleted />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentBoardId: state.currentBoardId
}); 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Board);
```

Here is the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(BoardForm)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(BoardForm)"
```

I do not understand why it's telling me about the store. I imported the disconnected version. Help?

Comment: You are calling connect, so it will look for a store, you should look into mocking the store for your tests and create a wrapper to test these components

Comment: But I am not testing the connected version. I am importing the disconnected version. I shouldn't have to mock the store.

Comment: mount will render all children, do any of the children call connect? its usually best to test a component in its natural use

Comment: yes, they do. That's a hassle...

Comment: thanks for the help